# what metric should I monitor for a spider in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

To make sure everything is working properly, what metric should I monitor for a general spider?

Currently, I'll monitor

1. the number of item returned. E.g. the percentage change should be less than 1%
2. the number of error in log file. E.g. the error number should be zero

is it enough for a general spider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't compute, because the answer depends solely on your specific use case and the goal of your scraping. The criteria/metric of spiders success is directly derived from your business logic. Just take a step back and ask yourself, what do I want to achieve with this spider? When you answer that, the metric you should monitor will be very clear.

Comment: Good to know there is no answer about my question

Comment: Actually there is - it is bound to your business logic :)